# Is there a way to prevent Prettier from touching <pre><code> blocks in HTML files?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, prettier

Prettier does a very nice job on HTML generally, but indents pre>code blocks.

I always want pre>code blocks unindented.

Seems like I should be able to configure this in .prettierignore, but can’t find a way that works.

blocks like:

```html
<pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-json">"operations": [
    "video-cloud/video/all",
    "video-cloud/playlist/all",
    "video-cloud/sharing-relationships/all",
    "video-cloud/notifications/all"
]</code></pre>
```

Get indented like this:

```html
      <pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-json">"operations": [
    "video-cloud/video/all",
    "video-cloud/playlist/all",
    "video-cloud/sharing-relationships/all",
    "video-cloud/notifications/all"
]</code></pre>
```

I want the block left untouched.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from a deleted answer:

> I personally don't use the extension but it seems like prettier has build in configuration for it: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

IIUIC, the solution is

```
<!-- prettier-ignore-start -->
block to keep
<!-- prettier-ignore-end -->
```

Voting to undelete the answer by "cas v.l." as it led me to the solution in seconds.

Comment: Nice. I also tried voting to undelete, but since it was deleted by a moderator, my vote seemed inert.

Comment: I have a bounty here about Prettier, in case you're interested. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/q/74020543/470749

Comment: I'm seeing it leave the ignore statements in after it's done though, is there a way to make it run and remove those markers?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore certain files, but you can't ignore parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference. In my case, I'm working on a react project. Adding "{` ..your code.. `}" after pre tag, prettier ignores the block. For example:

```
<pre>    
 {`
   <div className="row">
    <div className="col">
      ...
    </div>
   </div>
 `}
</pre>
```